# HttpServletResponse not overriding the parameters I set up

Tags: java, servlets, encoding, character-encoding

I have a web service app in Java and I'm trying to do an export functionality to export some data from the database to an excel file

For this I'm using **HttpServletResponse**, but even I set up a filename and a encoding type, the file exported is not using those.

I need to set up the name of the file with the corresponding export date and the encoding type to allow **UTF-8** characters like **á,ó,ñ, etc** --> This was fixed, see Edit 1 below.

Below you have my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    void export(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse r) {
        Response response = new Response();
        try {
            response = service.export();
            if(response.isSuccess()){
                r.setHeader( "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=export_20171216.xls");
                r.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                r.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                OutputStream out = r.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int length;
                while ((length = ((InputStream) response.getData()).read(buffer)) > 0){
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
            else{
                r.sendError(801, response.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
    }
```

As the result, I'm getting files with the name like 2ea4a24e-b0b4-4d50-9604-4fcdb3713b90.xls and inside the file words like: **NÃºmero** instead of **Número**

--- Edit 1
I fixed the stress vowels with the follwing code when creating the ByteArray

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-15"));
```

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Chrome Versión 64.0.3282.186 (Build oficial) (64 bits)
I also tried with Firefox and the file get another name, like a random name but with a different format than the one generated from Chrome

Answer (score 2):

If I got your issue correctly you are trying to keep filenames with symbols  that have to be encoded. According setHeaders method docs:

```
the header value If it contains octet string, it should be
     *            encoded according to RFC 2047
     *            (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt)
```

And more likely your input filenames are in ASCII that are octets. Try to use `java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder` with appropriate decoding when you set header with your fancy symbols.

A bit more explanations: ISO-8859-15 is not Unicode format and any symbol above of it leads to encoding the whole string for HTTP attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void sendResponse (InputStream inputData, String fileName, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws IOException {

    try {

        String contenttype = new ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap().getContentType(fileName);

        res.reset();
        res.setContentType(contenttype);
        res.addHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment;filename=\"%s\"", name));                
        ByteStreams.copy(inputData, res.getOutputStream());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:-I have used this in my code it works..
Let me know if still problem perisists

```
public void downloadFile(String fileName, String paramName, 
HttpServletResponse response) {
    File fileToBeDownloaded = null;
    InputStream fileInputStream = null;
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
         fileName);
        servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtil.copyCompletely(fileInputStream, servletOutputStream);

        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
        }
```